# Set Text Colour of Placeholder Text of UITextfield Apple TV

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, tvos, apple-tv

How to set Text Colour of Placeholder Text of UITextfield in both normal and focused state.

I am using code for setting placeholder text colour

```
self.emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Email Address" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:24], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];

self.passwordTextField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Password" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans" size:24], NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Default focus go to email textfield. Then the email textfield placeholder colour is black.

If the focus goes to password text field, then the placeholder text colour of email textfield is still black colour.

Answer (score -1):

You can set an `NSAttributedString` as the placeholder like so:

```
self.toTextField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"placeholderText" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}];
```

You can change the color, font family, size etc.. of the placeholder by using an  `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: I am doing the same thing. For the first time the placeholder text is coming as white colour but whenever focus goes to another textfield or button, the placeholder text colour is changed to black colour

Comment: Where are you setting this?

Comment: I am setting this in viewdidload

Comment: You can try runtime attributes from interface builder if you are using textfield from storyboard, i mean not taking programmatically ! @CodyMace